# Cannot create the unknown type, when adding dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, parsing, dynamically-generated

The Error:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Can't create unknown type
>   '{schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit}DoubleUpDown'.' (line number:
>   '1'; line position: '1706').'

I got the following code:

```
ParserContext context = new ParserContext();
context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");    
context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("materialDesign", "http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes");
context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("smtx", "clr-namespace:ShowMeTheXAML;assembly=ShowMeTheXAML");
context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("l", "clr-namespace:UIControls;assembly=UIControls");
context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008");
context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("sys", "clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib");
context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("xctk", "http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit");


Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
var ecod = new System.IO.MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(xaml));
TabItem element = (TabItem)XamlReader.Load(ecod, context);
DataControl.Items.Add(element);
```

As request of @mm8 this is a smaller **string xaml**:

```
string xaml = "<TabItem>" +
                  "<TabItem.Header>" +
                        "<StackPanel Orientation='Horizontal'>" +
                              "<TextBlock Text='Neutral' Foreground='Black' HorizontalAlignment='Center' VerticalAlignment='Center' Margin='0,0,0,0'/>" +
                        "</StackPanel>" +
                  "</TabItem.Header>" +
                  "<Grid Margin='0,20,0,0'>" +
                        "<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>" +
                             "<ColumnDefinition Width='1*'/>" +
                             "<ColumnDefinition Width='2*'/>" +
                             "<ColumnDefinition Width='1*'/>" +
                             "<ColumnDefinition Width='2*'/>" +
                        "</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>" +
                        "<StackPanel Grid.Column='0' Orientation='Vertical' HorizontalAlignment='Right'>" +
                             "<Label HorizontalAlignment='Right'>Sueldo:</Label>" +
                             "<Label HorizontalAlignment='Right'>Horas semanales:</Label>" +
                             "<Label HorizontalAlignment='Right'>Valor hora extra:</Label>" +
                             "<Label HorizontalAlignment='Right'>Valor hora extra nocturna:</Label>" +
                        "</StackPanel>" +
                        "<StackPanel Grid.Column='1' Orientation='Vertical'>" +
                             "<xctk:DoubleUpDown FontSize='16'/>" +
                             "<xctk:DoubleUpDown FontSize='16'/>" +
                             "<xctk:DoubleUpDown FontSize='16'/>" +
                             "<xctk:DoubleUpDown FontSize='16'/>" +
                        "</StackPanel>" +
                        "<StackPanel Grid.Column='2' Orientation='Vertical' HorizontalAlignment='Right'>" +
                             "<Label HorizontalAlignment='Right'>Valor de la hora(no extra):</Label>" +
                        "</StackPanel>" +
                        "<StackPanel Margin='10,0,0,0' Grid.Column='3' Orientation='Vertical' HorizontalAlignment='Left'>" +
                             "<TextBlock FontSize='18' Height='23'/>" +
                        "</StackPanel>" +
                 "</Grid>" +
             "</TabItem>";
```

Those controls are giving me the error, I get it as if the resource is not being called though I call it in the ParserContext as you can see in the code.

If I add it manually in the XAML it works like a charm, **other dll resources are working** so I don't think is all about BuildAction.

**What am I missing? Any other way to do this?**

Comment: You need to post the contents of `xaml` or at least a smaller version of it that can be used to reproduce your issue. How else do you think anyone should be able to help you out? Are you for example using any `StaticResources` in your XAML?

Comment: @mm8 added, sorry but I can't make it any shorter.

Comment: I'm curious why you do that strange stuff? There are much easier ways to do dynamic UIs.

Comment: @MaciekŚ. I'm learning, I'm doing it this way for testing purposes. Address me other ways so I can learn them too please.

Comment: On switching views: https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/. Easier. Testable.

Comment: If you map all appropriate namespaces and add the appropriate references it should work. It does for me.

Comment: @mm8 all maping added, yes thats why I know I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what exactly

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Can't create unknown type '{http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit}DoubleUpDown'.' (line number: '1'; line position: '1706').'

Comment: Did you really reference the toolkit assemblies from the assembly in which you call `XamlReader.Load`?

Comment: The not dynamically added example shouldn't work if this would be the case right? Because it works, it only fails when is added dynamically which is driving me crazy..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mapping the assembly in the parser like this:

```
context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("xctk", "clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit");
```

Instead of like this:

```
context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("xctk", "http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit");
```

Fixed the problem.